# How to use the `itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)` signal in qtHaskell

Tags: qt, haskell, qt4

I want to use the `itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)` signal in a **Haskell** program I'm writing where I am using **qtHaskell** for the GUI. To connect a function I have at other places done the following:

```
dummyWidget <- myQWidget
connectSlot object signal dummyWidget "customSlot()" $ f
```

Where `object` is some `QWidget` and `signal` is a string representing the signal, e.g. `"triggered()"`, and `f` is the function I want to be called when the signale is send.
The definition of `connectSlot` in the API is:

```
class Qcs x where
  connectSlot :: QObject a -> String -> QObject b -> String -> x -> IO ()
```

where the instances of`Qcs` are:

```
Qcs ()  
Qcs (QObject c -> String -> IO ())  
Qcs (QObject c -> Object d -> IO ())  
Qcs (QObject c -> Bool -> IO ())  
Qcs (QObject c -> Int -> IO ())  
Qcs (QObject c -> IO ())  
Qcs (QObject c -> OpenGLVersionFlag -> IO ())
```

The first Arguments passed is supposed to be the `QObject` of which I'm using a signal. As you can see, there is no instance where `f`, the function to connect to the signal, can have two further arguments to recieve the `QWidget` and the integer send by the signal. Is there a way to nevertheless connect that signal to a custom function?

Comment: qtHaskell is pretty much unused. I know of no example applications for it. Why not use gtk2hs or wxHaskell -- there's far more documentation.

Comment: Well, I like Qt, and someone has to be the first I suppose. Until the point where I wanted to use that signal it worked pretty well. If there is no solution I suppose I will use gtk2hs if it has to be.

Comment: @Don Stewart, indeed if anyone who tries using qtHaskell is advised to switch to gtk2hs, qtHaskell is going to stay unused :)

@nano, I suggest you ask the author, perhaps he'll be able to help.

Comment: Encouraging the use of unused and undocumented libraries by new users isn't necessarily the best experience for them.

Comment: @Don Stewart Don't worry. I like a challenge.
@David V. You are right, I'll e-mail the main developer a link to this question.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I'm leaving this answer here only as documentation. My suggestion was based on a misunderstanding and doesn't actually work in this situation.

---

Would it work to call `connectSlot` with a partially applied custom function, as in the ["Signals and Slots"](http://qthaskell.berlios.de/doc/primer/Signals%20and%20Slots.html) example in the [qtHaskell primer](http://qthaskell.berlios.de/doc/primer/)?

In that example the function `on_hello_clicked` has type `QMessageBox () -> MyQPushButton -> IO ()`, which seems to correspond to what you want your `f` to look like, except that you want an additional `Int` argument at the end.

The authors use this function with `connectSlot` by first applying it to their message box:

```
hello <- myQPushButton "Hello qtHaskell World"
resize hello (200::Int, 60::Int)
mb <- qMessageBox hello 
connectSlot hello "clicked()" hello "click()" $ on_hello_clicked mb
```

So while `on_hello_clicked` doesn't have a type that's an instance of `Qcs` (since it wants both a message box and a button), the partially applied `on_hello_clicked mb` does.

Comment: Yes, I have been doing this on other places, but at this point I do not think it would solve my problem, since the partially applied function would be the 5. argument of `connectSlot` and I still would not be able to get both the `QWidgetItem` and the integer as arguments for my function, which would tell me what item in a list was clicked. By the way, just getting the `QWidgetItem` and disregarding the integer does not seem to work either.